# Getting different row count for column family each time

Tags: cassandra

I have created 4 nodes cluster, and pointed the cluster from my client. After some time, i didn't point the cluster anywhere. But the row count keep on varying, it is decreasing and increasing for all column families.

what could be the reason?

Comment: How are you measuring the row count?

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CF_Name;

Comment: Is it constant if you use consistency level ALL?

Comment: When i set ALL i am getting equal no of count.

Comment: But when i set consistency level to ALL while reading, it is taking long time for retrieving. Is there any other way to get the exact row count for a column family?

Answer (score 0):

Counting number of rows in Cassandra is notoriously difficult (see my [blog post](http://www.wentnet.com/blog/?p=24) on the issue).

It looks like your issue is consistency.  The usual rules of consistency apply: if you require consistent reads, you need to make sure R + W > N (R=number of nodes required for read, W=number for writes, N=number of nodes).  A common way to do this is to read and write at CL.QUORUM.

Note that counting rows is *extremely* expensive, since it reads through all your data.  If this is a common operation you should find a different way of doing it, depending on your use case.